# obfuscate code with laravel mix

Tags: vue.js, uglifyjs, laravel-mix

I have a web app with laravel and vuejs.
I  use laravel-mix and in my `webpack.mix.js` i have:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');
mix.sourceMaps();
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

now I would obfuscate code, so all my components, how can I do this with laravel-mix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`npm run dev` will NOT uglify / minify your code, but `npm run production` WILL.

If you are looking to use uglify...

laravel mix is just a wrapper around webpack. So you can install the UglifyWepackPlugin here https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/

Afterwards, you can edit your mix.webpackConfig to use the plugin, as detailed here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#custom-webpack-configuration

Comment: for minify ok, but npm run production I can see my function with name of function in clear in app.js minified so more precisely I would obfsuscate my code. I edit my question.

Comment: https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator use this, this plugin is working perfect

Answer (score 7):

Install https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator and https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/webpack-obfuscator.
After that you need to include de plugin in the webpack configuration, you can do that adding the next code in webpack.mix.js file.

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
let JavaScriptObfuscator = require('webpack-obfuscator');

mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        new JavaScriptObfuscator ({
            rotateUnicodeArray: true
        }, ['excluded_bundle_name.js'])
    ],
});

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

After that all your js files will be obfuscater.